# How to set condition in excel vba based on cell value?

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I want to ask one question.
I have codes of how I can save last row of excel in vba,
But in my codes I want to add one condition where for example last row selected will be saved if cell.value of column E = "disable" then

'save like this
WB.SaveAs filename:="C:\New Folder\" & filename, FileFormat:=51

End If

This is my codes

```
Sub Increment()
   ' change A1 to the cell you wish to Increment
   Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + 1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call SaveLastLine
End Sub

Sub SaveLastLine()

    'Variable declaration
    Dim score As String
        Dim WB As Workbook, _
            filename As String

        'Turn off screen updating and alerts
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        'Make a copy of the last line of Active Sheet

        newName = ActiveSheet.Name
        Range("B1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    Call Increment

        FileNane1 = Range("A1").Value

        Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
        filename = newName & FileNane1 & ".xlsx"
        WB.SaveAs filename:="C:\New Folder\" & filename, FileFormat:=51

        'Restore screen updating and alerts

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Is there someone who can help me to add one condition in my vba codes?

Please anyone can help me.

Comment: Did you actually write any of that code? Because your question is basically just "How do I use an If Then statement".

Comment: What I wanna mean is, before of executing line of SaveAs I wanna set condition which will check either cell value of column E is equal to "Disable" if is Disable then execute SaveAs line else I will set other path of SaveAs.  Means that I wanna save in two different folders.

Comment: And so?! that's not the answer!! below is the really answer. I'm not good in vb codes, except PHP JAVA and so on.

Comment: I retracted my last comment because I felt it was too harsh, but based on your response, I would like to reiterate: Please do yourself the favor of actually learning coding as a skill. By only copying complete sections of code, you are no more learning VBA than I am learning Spanish by dumping a book into google translate.

Comment: Yes Grade, I know how to study programming languages. As I said above I'm good in Java, PHP, C and C++ even database but I'm still studying vba. I tried to write that codes above except one part I asked here. So how can I set that the condition? or if it's possible send me the link.

Comment: I will provide a little guidance for you: your question is actually two: (1) "How can I use a logic branch based on a cell's value?" and (2) "How do I save an Excel file?". You already seem to know how to save an Excel file with VBA, so really your question is just "How can I use a logic branch based on a cell's value?" The answer can be found on Microsoft's MSDN page, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileName1 = Range("A1").Value
if FileName1 = "disable" then
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    filename = newName & FileNane1 & ".xlsx"
    WB.SaveAs filename:="C:\New Folder\" & filename, FileFormat:=51
end if
```

Comment: I think there's an issue with your code - you've set Filename1 to equal Range("A1").Value, but then later on you use "If Filename =...". Be consistent with your variables. To help with this, put Option Explicit at the top of all of your VBA modules; that will tell Excel to give an error when you use a name that you haven't declared yet.